# how to know the actual url from the rewrited url of remote site

Tags: mod-rewrite

exactly as stated in the title i know it can be easy to know the actual url in we have access to the site code and files including the .htaccess file but this is not the case here, what i am talknig about is if the site is remote, here is examble:

this link

```
http://www.streamhunter.eu/free-live-video-streaming-beach-volleyball-long-beach-grand-slam-2013-volleyball-beach-volleyball-160997.html
```

how to know the actual url before rewrite which i think may be somthing like that

```
http://www.streamhunter.eu/index.php?a=243&b=65&c=63
```

the question here how to know the exact url?

I dont know if it possible or not.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: @icedwater i wonder if it possible for learning purposes

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "actual URL"? If you're accessing a remote site, the original URL is whatever you requested from the server.

Comment: i mean the thr original url before rewrited with mod_rewrite

Comment: ... so, whatever you requested from the server then? I'd like to be helpful, but I don't understand why, if this is a remote site that you're accessing, your program doesn't know the URL it requested.